# Transformation of fats in presence of alcohol

Tags: everyday-chemistry, alcohols, food-chemistry, fats

I have always observed when cooking that if I have some amount of fat like oil or butter in a hot frying pan and I pour some alcohol like wine on it, then there is a reaction and the quantity of matter which is left is strongly reduced because it evaporates. What is the name of this reaction and what are its products? Why is it used in cooking?

Maybe the question has been asked somewhere in a more erudite way, however I know really little about chemistry so I couldn't find it on neither Google nor SE.

Comment: There is no reaction. Alcohol (and water, for that matter) quickly evaporates and vanishes; that's it.

Comment: So what remains is really the fats and the alcohol ? How can you prove it ?

Comment: I can't prove a thing, if my words come across to you with the _opposite_ meaning. Did I say anything about the alcohol? Did I say that it will remain? What did I say, really?

Comment: really not much you are right about that ! Elaborate your answer then, please

Comment: you actuall *said* there is no reaction. So both should remain if they do not completey evaporate. It is true, if my frying pan is very hot then everything will be evaporated and solid, black and stinky and I won't eat. And that's bad for me so I avoid it in general, therefore the temperature is sufficiently low in the problem considered so that I have **some stuff remaining**. The question is : **what is this stuff** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just not forget that we're dealing with cooking, i.e., ridiculously complex chemical composition.

The main factor here is temperature.

- Alcohol (Ethyl Ethanol) evaporates, as Ivan said. Although, since you're using a beverage (wine, beer, etc.) and not **pure** alcohol, so you're going to have some remains from the beverage, such as sugars, tannins, complex acids, etc.
- If you have a very high temperature, you can have your organic compounds - the aforementioned sugars, tannins, the fats that you already put there, etc. - degrading and reacting with each other. You DO NOT want that happening, because the products can taste or smell really bad (for example, rancid smells are the product of fat degradation)

Speaking of cooking (and I do that a lot), you shouldn't add an alcoholic beverage or ANY kind of liquid **directly** to heated fat - butter or oil, not only because of the safety problem but because it is actually counterproductive. When you fry something - like meat or onions - and then add alcohol to form a reduction you're using the solvent properties of a alcohol + water solution to maximize de-scaling of the remnants in your frying pan (which are the products of a reaction called Maillard's reaction, very tasty ;)) and have maximum flavor in your sauce by adding the flavor from the beverage.

Hope it helped!